# swiftui subview reappear after click the back button and update state data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Very strange behavior.

Click the back button on the subpage (Subview) to return to the main page (ContentView). However, the subpage (Subview) automatically opens again. Why?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var things: [String] = []
    @State var count: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(things.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(things[index])
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                update()
            }
           
            .navigationTitle("a")
            .toolbar{
                NavigationLink(destination: Subview(count: $count), label: {
                    Text("sub")
                })
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func update() {
        things = []
        for i in 0...count {
            things.append(String(i))
        }
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    var count : Binding<Int>

    var body: some View {
        Text("sub")
            .onAppear {
                count.wrappedValue += 1
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Pressing back button goes back, but then automatically pushes to new page again]

Comment: You should describe more in detail what your problem is. I can't figure out your actual question.

Comment: @D.Mika I want to update main page  when returning to the main page from the subpage, but, the question is, the sub page automatically opens again. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationLink` should always be inside a `NavigationView`. If you put it in the toolbar or some other place, you might run into weird issues.

Instead, use the [`init(destination:isActive:label:)`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui) initializer. Then set the `presentingNextPage` property to `true` when you want to present the next page.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var things: [String] = []
    @State var count: Int = 0
    @State var presentingNextPage = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(things.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(things[index])
                }
                
                /// placeholder navigation link
                NavigationLink(destination: Subview(count: $count), isActive: $presentingNextPage) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.update()
            }
            .navigationTitle("a")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("sub") {
                        presentingNextPage = true /// set to true
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func update() {
        things = []
        for i in 0...count {
            things.append(String(i))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Press button to present next page, pressing back doesn't automatically present again.]

Comment: In my case. I was editing the list from another view{}. Expecting @ObservableEvent to update the list{}. But if the new list{} contained more rows, the first rows contained stale information. Placing the update() is like a repaint event each time the list{} is seen and corrected my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put "onAppear{...}" on the NavigationView not the List, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var things: [String] = []
    @State var count: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(things.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(things[index])
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("a")
            .toolbar{
                NavigationLink(destination: Subview(count: $count), label: {
                    Text("sub")
                })
            }
        }
        .onAppear {   // <---
            update()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but, just tried it,
Doing so will cause onAppear not to execute when returning to the main page from the subpage.
That is, the content of the main page will not be updated