SwiftUI - Having issues with automatically switching focus to the next field
As a beginner in SwiftUI, I am creating a custom OTP view which is working fine, but I am facing an issue with switching focus to the next field. I expect that when the user types, it should automatically switch focus to the next available OTP field.
Please help!!!
struct CustomOtpFieldView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var otpFields: [String]
    var index: Int
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.green))
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                let allowedCharacters = "0123456789"
                if !allowedCharacters.contains(newValue) {
                    text = String(newValue.filter { allowedCharacters.contains($0) })
                }
                if text.count > 1 {
                    text = String(text.prefix(1))
                }
                
                handleOtpFieldChange()
            }
            .onAppear {
                if index == 0 {
                    isFocused = true
                }
            }
    }

    private func handleOtpFieldChange() {
        if text.count == 1 && index < otpFields.count - 1 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                isFocused = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    otpFields[index + 1] = ""
                    isFocused = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@State private var otpFields: [String]

self.fieldsCount = 6
self._otpFields = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: "", count: fieldsCount))

ForEach(0..<fieldsCount, id: \.self) { index in
                    CustomOtpFieldView(text: $otpFields[index], otpFields: $otpFields, index: index)
                }

  Thanks in advance.

Watch Demysitfy SwiftUI, using ranges is unsafe. Also whatever tutorial you are following is really old. Look at the official ones, SwiftUI has changed a lot. TextField supports Double and Int natively.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388014/cant-convert-string-to-int-in-appstorage/75388866#75388866

Yeah the way you're doing it seems a little off, here is how I did it. First create an enum FocusField this will contain all our fields.
enum FocusField {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

Then I created a reusable View called 'SingleDigitTextFieldView' that does the validation for me on the onChange modifier. This is how it looks like.
struct SingleDigitTextFieldView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState.Binding var ff: FocusField?
    var assignedField: FocusField
    var nextField: FocusField?
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("0", text: $text)
            .focused($ff, equals: assignedField)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.green))
            .onChange(of: text) { oldValue, newValue in
                let exceptedValues = "0123456789"
                if exceptedValues.contains(newValue) {
                    if newValue.count > 0 {
                        ff = nextField
                    }
                }
                else {
                    text = ""
                }
            }
    }
}

Then you can use it like this.
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var ff: FocusField?
    @State private var oneText: String = ""
    @State private var twoText: String = ""
    @State private var threeText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            SingleDigitTextFieldView(
                text: $oneText,
                ff: $ff,
                assignedField: .one,
                nextField: .two
            )
            
            SingleDigitTextFieldView(
                text: $twoText,
                ff: $ff,
                assignedField: .two,
                nextField: .three
            )
            
            SingleDigitTextFieldView(
                text: $threeText,
                ff: $ff,
                assignedField: .three,
                nextField: nil
            )
        }
    }
}

You can do more validation in the onChange modifier. Happy Coding.

Thank you so much. it helps me a lot but I am now considering making a single component in which sending the fieldCount (number of OTP fields) parameter which creates the OTP fields accordingly fieldCount parameter.

I created this reusable OTPFieldView SwiftUI component where I've utilized the @FocusState property wrapper and created a FocusPin enum to manage focus on each field dynamically. The onChange handler on each TextField plays a key role in moving the focus to the next field once a digit is entered
I hope it proves helpful for others facing the same challenge.
You can download the full source code in my Github repo
https://github.com/JayantBadlani/OTPFieldView-SwiftUI
SOURCE CODE:
import SwiftUI
import Combine


// A SwiftUI view for entering OTP (One-Time Password).
struct OTPFieldView: View {
    
    @FocusState private var pinFocusState: FocusPin?
    @Binding private var otp: String
    @State private var pins: [String]
    
    var numberOfFields: Int
    
    enum FocusPin: Hashable {
        case pin(Int)
    }
    
    init(numberOfFields: Int, otp: Binding<String>) {
        self.numberOfFields = numberOfFields
        self._otp = otp
        self._pins = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: "", count: numberOfFields))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(0..<numberOfFields, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("", text: $pins[index])
                    .modifier(OtpModifier(pin: $pins[index]))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .onChange(of: pins[index]) { newVal in
                        if newVal.count == 1 {
                            if index < numberOfFields - 1 {
                                pinFocusState = FocusPin.pin(index + 1)
                            } else {
                                // Uncomment this if you want to clear focus after the last digit
                                // pinFocusState = nil
                            }
                        }
                        else if newVal.count == numberOfFields, let intValue = Int(newVal) {
                            // Pasted value
                            otp = newVal
                            updatePinsFromOTP()
                            pinFocusState = FocusPin.pin(numberOfFields - 1)
                        }
                        else if newVal.isEmpty {
                            if index > 0 {
                                pinFocusState = FocusPin.pin(index - 1)
                            }
                        }
                        updateOTPString()
                    }
                    .focused($pinFocusState, equals: FocusPin.pin(index))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // Set focus to the current field when tapped
                        pinFocusState = FocusPin.pin(index)
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Initialize pins based on the OTP string
            updatePinsFromOTP()
        }
    }
    
    private func updatePinsFromOTP() {
        let otpArray = Array(otp.prefix(numberOfFields))
        for (index, char) in otpArray.enumerated() {
            pins[index] = String(char)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateOTPString() {
        otp = pins.joined()
    }
}

struct OtpModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var pin: String
    
    var textLimit = 1
    
    func limitText(_ upper: Int) {
        if pin.count > upper {
            self.pin = String(pin.prefix(upper))
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onReceive(Just(pin)) { _ in limitText(textLimit) }
            .frame(width: 40, height: 48)
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
    }
}

struct OTPFieldView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text("VERIFICATION CODE")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
            OTPFieldView(numberOfFields: 5, otp: .constant("54321"))
                .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        }
    }
}

EXAMPLE: HOW TO USE
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var otp: String = ""
    @FocusState private var isOTPFieldFocused: Bool
    private let numberOfFieldsInOTP = 6
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text("VERIFICATION CODE")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
            
            OTPFieldView(numberOfFields: numberOfFieldsInOTP, otp: $otp)
                .onChange(of: otp) { newOtp in
                    if newOtp.count == numberOfFieldsInOTP {
                        // Verify OTP
                    }
                }
                .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
            
            Text("Entered OTP: \(otp)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                isTextFieldFocused = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

