# SwiftUI: Changing app theme with toggle issue

Tags: swiftui

In my application I have a NavigationLink that takes you to a SettingsView.

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView(user: $user)) {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                        .accessibilityLabel("Settings")
                }
            }
```

As of now the SettingsView is very simple. It only has a Toggle that lets the user change back and forth between dark and light mode.

```
struct SettingsView: View {

@Binding var user: User

var body: some View {
    List {
        Toggle("Dark Mode", isOn: $user.darkMode)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Settings")
}
```

}

In the ContentView, the scheme is set with this line.

```
HomeView(user: $user)
    .colorScheme(user.darkMode ? .dark : .light)
```

When this happens the views will reload as expected, but it essentially acts as if I've pressed that NavigationLink button again. It opens another SettingsView on top of the one that was already open. Is there any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67650235/14351818

Comment: @aheze hey that definitely helped. It doesn't do the what it was doing before. It does close the SettingsView entirely, but I'd prefer that over what it was doing before. Thank you.